# Class: sets the real number to a random number which is between two other numbers

Tags: bluej

Having troubles with the math portion of a problem.

the class is supposed to set the value to a random number between two other numbers (inclusive).

ex. If a 20 were passed in, and the average was 70, then it would generate a random number between 60 and 80, then store it as the value.

I know part of the formula is: (average - range/2) and (average + range/2).

range = number passed in.
average = original number.

Answer (score 0):

All that's left for you to do is use a `Random` object to get random numbers in your range.  Here's code that gets ten of them in a loop.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumber
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int range = 20;
       int average = 70;
       int base = average - range/2;

       Random rand = new Random();

       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           int num = rand.nextInt(range + 1) + base;
           System.out.println(num);
       }
   }
}
```

Since calling the [`nextInt(int n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) method returns a random number from 0 (inclusive) to n (exclusive), you have to pass it `range + 1` because you want both ends of your range to be included, not just the low end.  With the value used above, the call to `rand.nextInt(range + 1)` will return values from 0 - 20 inclusive.  When the `base` value of 60 is added, these values are translated to 60 - 80.